# Erro Inesperado na classe PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou quebrando a cebeça com esse código ja faz algum tempo, é a primeira vez que estou utilizando a classe PDO do PHP e estou tendo um erro que não sei como resolver.

```
<?php
include "conexao.php";
$banco = new Banco(); //Instanciando o banco de dados

$filtro = array("/", "-", ".", "(", ")", " "); //Filtro de caracteres indesejados

$nome = $_GET['nome'];
$senha = $_GET['senha'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
$nascimento = str_replace($filtro, "", $_GET['nascimento']);
$telefone = str_replace($filtro, "", $_GET['telefone']);

$resultado = $banco->prepare("INSERT INTO clientes(id_cliente, nome_cliente, 
                                                         email_cliente, telefone_cliente, senha_cliente, 
                                                         data_nasc_cliente) VALUES(NULL, :nome, :email, 
                                                          :telefone, :senha, :nascimento");

$resultado->execute(array(
  ':nome' => $nome,
  ':email' => $email,
  ':telefone' => $telefone,
  ':senha' => $senha,
  ':nascimento' => $nascimento                                     
));
```

O código a cima não está inserindo na tabela.

Comment: Qual erro é exibido? `print_r($resultado->errorInfo());`. `id_cliente` é um campo com auto incremento? tem certeza que usando `NULL` vai dar certo?

Comment: @stderr O auto increment está correto, o `print_r` gerou um erro que não consigo indentificar no código `Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4 )`

Comment: @stderr não, continua dando o mesmo erro

Comment: @stderr os retirei, o erro continua o mesmo

Comment: Desisti de usar PDO no projeto, estou usando mysqli agora

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estava Faltando fechar um parenteses no final da string de conexão

```
...VALUES(NULL, :nome, :email, :telefone, :senha, :nascimento)");
```

FML